# Required parameter issue dtsx power shell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, parameters, ssis, etl

**Required parameter issue dtsx power shell script.**
Below package have only 2 parameters and both are passed still getting error(you need to specify values for required parameters)
refer attached image for more details
Is it required to pass connection manager values in dtsx?

```
dtexec /ISServer "\SSISDB\DEV\PopulateData.dtsx" 
/server xxxxxxxsql.com,3181 /Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::Environment].Properties[Value];"[sql7891874] Dev"
 /SET \Package.Variables[User::ProcessData].Properties[Value];
 "\"Data Source=xxxxxxxsql.com,3181;Initial Catalog=Staging;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;\""
```

*Screenshot*

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So I'm having trouble understanding how this question differs from your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594412/how-to-add-parameters-and-conn-managers-in-power-shell-script-for-ssis/54602534#54602534).  Additionally, you specify PowerShell here but in your screenshot, shows a SQL Agent job with a job step type of SQL Server Integration Services. Where does the PowerShell fit into all of this?

Comment: We are running ssis jobs through powershell script in the server. For this we will use AutoSys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a scheduled job for the ssis package then right click the job and generate script.
The generated script contain command line package execution script.